# Scalar Insert Query return null

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, sybase, tableadapter

I am using **Sybase** Server, project connected to DB via DataSet. 
I created insert query on my tableAdapter

```
INSERT INTO DBA.opt_port(port, port_level, prim, kluch_raz, speed, agr_port, port_bad)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Query execute mode is set to Scalar, but after calling this query it always return null.

```
var newId = opt_portTableAdapter.InsertNewPort(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text),
                        textBox3.Text, kluch, int.Parse(textBox4.Text), ToNullableInt(textBox5.Text),
                        ToNullableInt(textBox6.Text))
```

I also added parameter to query parameters collection, set Direction as ReturnValue and SourceColumn to my primary key, but still null result.
When I manually check new record in my table, it exist and it's pKey is set.
How can I get my primary key after inserting row?

Table creation query is

```
CREATE TABLE "DBA"."opt_port" (
    "port" smallint NOT NULL,
    "port_level" smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "prim" char(128) NULL,
    "n_pp" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT autoincrement,
    "kluch_raz" smallint NULL,
    "speed" smallint NULL,
    "agr_port" smallint NULL,
    "port_bad" smallint NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "n_pp" )
);
```

Comment: try executing the procedure directly in the sql with the params you re passing and check!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_opt_port]
     ( @input1 varchar(50),
      @input2 varchar(50),
      @id int output
)

AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO DBA.opt_port
        (port, port_level)
        VALUES (@input1 , @input2)

```
  SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
  RETURN  @id
```

END

Comment: please create procedure  like above example.